# Anchoring CAT6 cable and a cameras to hardie plank

Tags: concrete, masonry, caulking, security, ethernet

I am going to drill through hardie plank to run CAT6 to a camera. The run outside the house will be about 10' to 12'. Total run is about 30'. I wanted to ask if I am going about this the correct way.

1. [Going to use masonry bits to drill through the hardie plank for the CAT 6 drop probably 1/4" or 5/16" bit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DEWALT-7-Piece-Carbide-Masonry-Drill-Bit-for-Hammer-Drill/1001001776)
2. [Run outdoor Shireen CAT6 cable](https://www.shireeninc.com/osc/dc-2030-outdoor-cat6-with-dry-gel-tape-utp-by-ft)
3. [Attach coax clamps to Hardie Plank](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-4-in-Coaxial-Cable-Clamp-RG-6-20-Pack-PEC-31525WA/205588202)
4. [Secure coax clamps and camera to Hardie Plank via Gardner Bender Concrete Anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Gardner-Bender-100-Pack-Concrete-Anchors-Drill-Bit-Included/4638929)
5. Not sure what type of caulk to use to seal the hole for the CAT6 cable and to seal around the camera??

Here is a picture of where I was going to install. Yellow line is CAT6 and red X's are the cameras.

Anything I am missing and what type of caulk would I use to seal hole and around the junction box for the camera?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using pre-built cables, make sure your hole is big enough for the RJ45 connector to go through. If you're crimping ends up on a ladder... have fun! :)

When drilling holes for the anchors, be sure to use the proper size bit for the anchors you're purchasing. You might need 2 different bits (one for the cable, one for the anchors), don't scrimp a few bucks by trying to make do with just one. The reduced frustration on a ladder will more than make up for a few dollars for an extra bit.

Other than that, you plan seems sound.

As far as caulk, I'd use a good, exterior grade clear silicone. Put a blob of caulk on the anchor (like the red one in the cable clamp link), then put the thing to be attached over the blob & drive the screw through the caulk. Don't put the caulk over the screw head unless you like guaranteeing frustration in the future if/when someone has to take this down. Cleaning the caulk out of the screw head so you can get a driver back in can be a nightmare.

Comment: That is SOLID advice. I know there is a good reason but why put silicone on anchor then attach the clamp? Also, is there a particular type of silicone caulk you can recommend or will any type of silicone work? Thank you for the response!

Comment: Almost forgot, can I use a regular drill to drill through Hardie board?

Comment: For drilling through the Hardie Board, a regular drill should be fine. Actually, other than that you've chosen hammer drill bits (based on your link), you should be able to use a regular drill to drill into the brick behind them, as well. You're drilling small holes and not going very deep into the brick, so you should get there just fine. I would imagine that you could chuck those hammer drill bits into a regular drill and they'd work fine (haven't tried it myself), giving you the flexibility to switch to a hammer drill in the future if you needed to.